# Правильное удаление элемента массива

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, производительность

Здесь [Пишем быстрый и экономный код на JavaScript](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248111/) написано:

> **Советы по использованию массивов**
>
> Не удаляйте элементы. Если в массиве образуются пустые места, V8
>   переключается на словарный метод работы с массивами, что делает скрипт
>   ещё медленнее.

В коде ниже я удаляю 3-й элемент. Команда splice просто выбрасывает элемент из массива (и это касается статьи с хабра), или она переформирует массив, после удаления элемента, и пустых мест там не остаётся?

С точки зрения быстродействия, какой наилучший способ удаления элемента из массива по его индексу (интересует вплоть до десятков миллисекунд) ?

```
function a(){
    var b = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        b[i] = i;
    }

    b.splice(2, 1);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Рекомендации про удаление относится к использованию оператора `delete`, ибо он оставляет вместо элемента на своем месте `undefined`

Comment: наилучший способ создать новый массив без ненужных элементов

Comment: Если элементы удаляются с конца, то `pop` или уменьшить `length`.

Comment: Да, но какой ответ на мой вопрос? Удаление из середины, самый быстрый способ.